# How to take user message and use it as command

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I use Python 3 and python-telegram-bot .
The user send a message like this "When i say ... say ...." example : "When i say Hi say Hello " 
i can take "Hi and Hello" from the message 
My problem is how to set Hi in bot to when user say hi my bot say Hello

i try to use MessageHandler for example :

```
MessageHandler(Variable,Callback)
```

Variable have hi for example
but when i send hi my bot does not send Hello

but when i send hi my bot does not send Hello

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use an event. `on_message` should work. Try this:(rewrite)

```py
bot.msg = "Hi" #just create a command in which you would assign a text to bot.msg

   @bot.listen()
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.content.lower() == bot.msg.lower()   #you can set a bot variable, I'll use `bot.msg`
    await message.channel.send("Hello")
```